# How to extract merged proguard rules

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I need to extract final proguard rules file, with all rules for a project. 
I've greped it in the project  directory but no luck

Answer (score 20):

Add this line to your proguard-rules.pro to get a file with the merged proguard configuration of your project.

```
    -printconfiguration "build/outputs/mapping/configuration.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

After building with proguard you should have а file

> app/build/proguard-configuration.txt

This file contains all rules for a project.